# Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm getting that error for the line:

```
$S = (s_0,S), ahol s_0 = x_1 := <>,...,x_n := <> és S = \{x_0, x_1 := lorem(x_0), hiext(x_1,f_0(x_0.lov)), ha \ x_0 \not\equiv <> \\ ,...,$ \\
```

I'm very new to LaTeX, and don't quite understand what this means. Could you help?

Comment: You're misusing math mode: formulas should be segregated from text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `\acute{e}` instead of `é` in math mode, but I think it depends on your inputenc.

I don't have that error and your code works fine (even if is a too long line in math mode with no breaks).

Comment: Note you should only use `\acute` if it is denoting a math oeration, not if it is a natural language word containing é which is I think the case here.

Comment: Yes, my answer supposes that in math mode there are only math symbols or operations, otherwise you have to use \text{} inside $..$. It's correct?

Comment: yes but that is not the case here, "és" is "and"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: He's right, everything in math mode must be math or else enclosed in `\text{}` (or `\mbox{}` etc).  Here the word meaning "and" should be marked as plain non-mathematical text.

Answer (score 6):

You should not set natural language words in math mode (although you only get an error for the accented letters)

The markup should be more like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}% I think? :-)

\begin{document}

$S = (s_0,S)$,
ahol 
$s_0 = x_1 := \langle\rangle,\dots,x_n := \langle\rangle$
 és 
\[S = \{x_0, x_1 := \operatorname{lorem}(x_0),
\operatorname{hiext}(x_1,f_0(x_0.\mathrm{lov})),\]
ha 
$x_0 \not\equiv \langle\rangle$

\end{document}
```